# Make python __doc__ property display correctly in a Windows CMD window?

Tags: python

In Windows, if I open a command prompt, start python, and inspect something using its __doc__ property, it doesn't display correctly.  Instead of the lines being separated, I see one continuous string with the newline character every once and a while.

Is there a way to make it appear correctly?

Here's an example of what I see:

>>> hashlib.__doc__

'hashlib module - A common interface to many hash functions.\n\nnew(name, string=\'\') - returns a n
ew hash object implementing the\n                       given hash function; initializing the hash\n
                       using the given string data.\n\nNamed constructor functions are also availabl
e, these are much faster\nthan using new():\n\nmd5(), sha1(), sha224(), sha256(), sha384(), and sha5
12()\n\nMore algorithms may be available on your platform but the above are\nguaranteed to exist.\n\
nNOTE: If you want the adler32 or crc32 hash functions they are available in\nthe zlib module.\n\nCh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
>>> print hashlib.__doc__
```

or (v3)

```
>>> print(hashlib.__doc__)
```

Comment: What gimel said goes for any string with a newline in it.  I know this won't show up right in a comment, but:
>>> "\n".join(["hello world", "goodbye world"]);
'hello world\ngoodbye world'
>>> print _;
hello world
goodbye world

Answer (score 6):

Rather than pulling `__doc__` yourself, try this:

```
>>> help(hashlib)
```

It will give you a nicely formatted summary of the module, including (but not limited to) the docstring.

Comment: Thanks--I'm sure I'll use this in addition to the solution gimel gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
def help_(obj):
    if type(obj).__name__ == 'ufunc':
        print obj.__doc__
    else:
        help(obj)
```